# JPA query not in subquery relationship table

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I'd like to know how to make a query in JPA where content is not inside a "third table" responsible to make relationship manyToMany.

example:

```
SELECT id FROM A WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM A_B WHERE idB = @id)
```

In this case I have Table A, Table B, and the relationShip manytomany A_B

I tried with CriteriaQuery and subquery, but it didn't work. Actually, it returned none result.

Does somebody have any example for this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got my solution!

I don't know if it is completely correct, so, if someone see an error, please let me know.

The end query, created by JPA become this:

```
select maingroup0_.GroupId as GroupId1_, maingroup0_.idGroupAttendanceType as idGroupA2_1_, maingroup0_.name as name1_ from TUnPbxGroup maingroup0_ where maingroup0_.GroupId not in  (select maingroup1_.GroupId from TUnPbxGroup maingroup1_ inner join THolidayGroup listholida2_ on maingroup1_.GroupId=listholida2_.GroupId inner join THoliday holiday3_ on listholida2_.IdHoliday=holiday3_.IdHoliday where holiday3_.IdHoliday=2)
```

The code:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<MainGroup> query = cb.createQuery(MainGroup.class);
    Root<MainGroup> root = query.from(MainGroup.class);
    query.select(root);

    Subquery<Long> subquery = query.subquery(Long.class);
    Root<MainGroup> subRoot = subquery.from(MainGroup.class);
    subquery.select(subRoot.<Long>get("id"));
    Join<Holiday, Holiday> maingroups = subRoot.join("listHolidays");       
    subquery.where(cb.equal(maingroups.get("id"), holidayId));      

    query.where(cb.not(cb.in(root.get("id")).value(subquery))); 

    TypedQuery<MainGroup> typedQuery = em.createQuery(query);

    List<MainGroup> result = typedQuery.getResultList();
```

Comment: I'm not sure that example of the code is totally right, but it gave me an idea how to solve an issue with many-to-many relationship. Thanks!